# Pointer of struct changes

Tags: c++, null

```
#include<stack>
#include<iostream>

class Tree{
    private:
        struct tree{
            int val;
            tree * lChild;
            tree * rChild;
            tree * Parent;
        };
        tree *root;
    public:
        Tree();
        void insert(int x);
};

Tree::Tree(){
    root = NULL;
    std::cout<<"ROOT inside constructor : "<<root<<std::endl;
}

void Tree::insert(int x){
    tree *wst;
    wst->val = x;
    wst->lChild = NULL;
    wst->rChild = NULL;

    tree *temp = root;
    tree *p = NULL;


    std::cout<<"ROOT inside insert : "<<root<<std::endl;

    while(temp != NULL){
        p = temp;
        if(x < temp->val)
            temp = temp->lChild;
        else
            temp = temp->rChild;
    }

    std::cout<<x<<std::endl;

    wst->Parent = p;

    if(p == NULL){
        root = wst;
    }
    else{
        if(x < p->val)
            p->lChild = wst;
        else
            p->rChild = wst;
    }

}


int main(){
    Tree tree;

    tree.insert(404);

}
```

I want to check if pointer root is equal to NULL, but it does not seems too work. It seems like the pointer changes from 0 to 0x4 when I am inside the method insert. How can I check if pointer of struct is equal NULL?

EDIT In the insert method if tree doesn't have any nodes it should not enter first while loop, as root should be equall NULL. And my problem is that it enters this loop anyway and crashes when it checks for temp childrens(that are still not defined).

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: "It seems like the pointer changes from 0 to 0x4" how do you know? There are two `cout`s in the method and they print values of two different pointers. What is the output, what did you expect?

Comment: I'm seeing a definition for your `Tree`'s constructor outside the class but I don't see it's corresponding declaration?  Perhaps you forgot to change a few words?

Comment: @user463035818 I left wrong part of the code, I changed it to how it suppose to be like.

Comment: @NoName . Now include a `main` that exercises this, as well as whatever the mysterious `// do something` actually does, along with the expected output and actual output, and we may have something to work with.

Comment: still not clear how you get the idea that the value changes from `0` to `0x4`. You'd need at least two `cout`s to see that, or use a debugger

Comment: Also side note: use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` for pointers.

Comment: to expand on WhozCraig comment: We actually dont really care what is the real code you are working at (maybe we do, but usually your real code is out of scope and too much to be discussed here). What we need is code that does exactly expose the behaviour you describe, because if you tell us the code prints something when in fact it cannot compile then we cannot help you. Best is if you prepare a small example, compile it to see it does and only then post it

Comment: Fyi, `Tree tree = tree();` isn't valid C++. If anything that line should just be `Tree tree;` Going to ask again: Post a **real** [mcve] that produces your problem, with clear explanation of expected vs actual operation, or this question is destined to be closed.

Comment: @user463035818 now it should what my problem is.

Comment: how do you know it enters the while loop? maybe it does not. using a debugger >> guessing

Comment: @user463035818 In fact it _should_ not, because `temp == root == NULL` (and the OP, in fairness, does say this).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit memory could be corrupted in a way that causes the while loop to be executed, we dont know (and OP also states that while is entered). Anyhow, case is closed and its pointless to discuss details in presence of UB

Comment: @user463035818 That is true!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does `wst` point to?

```
tree *wst;
wst->val = x;
wst->lChild = NULL;
wst->rChild = NULL;
// [...]
wst->Parent = p;
```

Whoops! Your program has undefined behaviour. No wonder it crashes. :)

You probably need `tree* wst = new tree();` there. Don't forget to `delete` your nodes in the `Tree` destructor, too!

And I'd advise against having a type `Tree` plus a type `tree`; perhaps call the latter `Node` instead?

Comment: Notice how this problematic code was hidden by you until revision #5; please next time present a [MCVE] up-front (i.e. the _first_ time) so that we can avoid this drawn-out procedure!

Comment: That was a mistake it should not be a pointer but normal structure. I changed it to how it suppose to be and now everything works flawlessy. This pointer that doesn't point to anything was the cause of this issue. It somehow changed the value of root pointer.

Comment: @NoName no, it can not be a normal structure and it must be a pointer *(and you must initialise the pointer)*. Because normal structure will be created on stack and changed/deleted after the function ends. Then the pointer points to some part of memory, that was already overridden by other functions.

Comment: What Julo said. If you're going to store a pointer to it, you'll need to dynamically allocate it. From the sounds of it, you've made a slight improvement but now have a dangling pointer in your tree, effectively only _moving_ the problem elsewhere.